# Running jQuery after ajax complete fired from event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.imageItem', function(event) {
    $(this).slideUp()
});
```

Whenever the .imageItem is clicked a separate script fires Ajax (I don't have control over the other script) which manipulates the DOM.

So the .imageTable briefly slidesUp and hides but then it re-appears after the AJAX DOM manipulation done by the other script.

I tried waiting until the Ajax was complete but this isn't working:

```
$(document).on('click', '.imageItem', function(event) {
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {

    $(this).slideUp();

   });
});
```

I'm not sure why it's not working.

Comment: What is the other ajax callback doing exactly to the DOM? Is it causing .imageItem to be visible? Or is it manipulating some other part of the DOM?

Comment: if the other script isn't using jQuery for ajax the `ajaxComplete` won't catch it. Also `this` inside is probably the xhr settings object not a dom element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to keep track of which item was clicked and then use that one to hide in `ajaxComplete`:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
    if (img) {
        img.slideUp('slow');
        img = null;
    }
});

//To keep track of what item was clicked
var img = null;

$(".imageItem").on("click", function () {
    img = $(this);
});
```

You can see a working example in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/buvsbtru/), but as pointed by @charlietfl in comment it works if other script uses `jQuery`.